# Why does vim show differents color scheme on completion using tmux?

Tags: vim, tmux

Without tmux, it seems like that:
[image]

But If I use tmux, it change the color scheme like that:
[image]

Why?

How to set tmux.conf making vim show the same color scheme?

Comment: What's the respective output of `:hi Pmenu`?! Also, how many colors are available: `:set t_Co?`

Comment: Also, what is the output of `$ echo $TERM` inside and outside of tmux and what colorscheme do you use?

Comment: $ echo $TERM  inside and outside are both xterm @romainl

Comment: :hi Pmenu  inside and outside are both
Pmenu          xxx ctermfg=0 ctermbg=13 guibg=Magenta,
but outside the color of xxx is pink and inside is grey
@IngoKarkat

Comment: :set t_Co? are both 256 @IngoKarkat

Comment: Then the problem does not lie with Vim, but with the terminal's interpretation of the sent color sequences.

Comment: If I export TERM=screen-256color tmux, then it seems ok;
If I export TERM=xterm, I must use command like "TERM=screen-256color tmux";
so it means tmux just support screen-256color??? @IngoKarkat

Answer (score 0):

try to add `export TERM=screen-256color` 
or
`export TERM=xterm-256color` in your ~/.bashrc

Then to restart the terminal.

Comment: I have tred this but it proved to be no use.